# Can the plane be covered by open disjoint one dimensional intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I remember I heard this question a while ago but have never figured it out. Let an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ of the form $(a,b)$. Now, imaging placing it in $\mathbb{R}^2$, anywhere we want while keeping its length but perhaps rotating it if we want. Essentially this creates a line segment without its start/endpoints parametrized by

$P(1-t)+Qt$ for $0<t<1$ where $P$ and $Q$ are its start and end points and with length $||P-Q||=b-a$.

As an example, if we take the unit interval $(0,1)$, we can place it as it is in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $(0,1)\times \{0\}$ or we can rotate it as $\{1\}\times (0,1)$ etc. I hope it is clear what I mean. My question is the following.

Can we cover the entire $\mathbb{R}^2$ with disjoint such "open intervals" or if you prefer, line segments of finite length without their start/endpoints?

I don't remember if the initial question I read was using only unit intervals, or of any length $(a,b)$ and I don't know if that plays a role in the answer but as a gut feeling, I doubt it does. My impression is that the answer is negative and we can't cover the plane in such a manner, or if it is possible it would use some weird abstract construction perhaps involving AC. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: It seems that I could have phrased my wording a bit better although that was my last paragraph in the post above that I wasn't certain if it mattered whether we need to have fixed length intervals or not. Apparently it does, it is impossible with using only fixed length intervals but it is possible if we allow intervals of different lengths. Proof of impossibility in one case given in a paper given in the answers, and a construction in the other case is given by some answers and also found in that paper itself. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Randall how does that imply that it cannot be done for $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @VIVID Well, it's completely obvious that you *can* cover $\mathbb{R}$ by disjoint open intervals embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @VIVID The intersection of an open interval in $\Bbb R^2$ and a copy of $\Bbb R$ in $\Bbb R^2$ need not be an open interval in that copy of $\Bbb R$. In fact it's possible to partition the plane with closed nondegenerate intervals, while this cannot be done for $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Esoog Interesting question!

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: that's very interesting. Can you describe that partition into closed intervals or give a reference please.

Comment: @Rob http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.503.5533

Comment: As here is some controversy in the answers ... Do you require all the intervals to be of the same length or not? - can you please confirm? It seems that, if they are required to be the same length, there is no solution, and if not, then there is a solution, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ah, I now understand the flaw in my previous reasoning.

Comment: It can be done trivially with infinite-length intervals. Your question doesn't specify that the intervals be of finite length.

Comment: Hi, your edit still doesn't preclude infinite-length intervals, which are all the "same length".

Comment: @Spencer Even before the edit, it was clearly stated in the post "line segments of finite length". Also, it is is more or less standard notation that if someone mentions an interval of the form $(a,b)$ that $a,b \in \mathbb{R} $ thus excluding infinite intervals. In any case, I feel it is adequately clarified.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess is that you can do it.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Notice first that you can tile the plane with open (rectangular) triangles and open squares. In  fact, grid the plane with rotated/translated copies of the segment $(0,1)$, obtaining a regular lattice of open squares (notice you have still to cover the endpoints of the segments).
Now add diagonal segments of length $2\sqrt 2$ in order to cut one square every 2 into 4 rectangular triangles. You can do it by shifting every parallel diagonal by $\sqrt 2$.

But now you can cover any open triangle (that is, without its perimeter) and open square with segments parallel to one of the sides.

Comment: I think this fails to cover the points with integer coordinates.

Comment: @EthanBolker added a picture. I think every integer coordinate point is covered

Comment: That looks a lot better than a guess to me!

Comment: I think this works.  In my previous questions the intervals were supposed to all be the same length.  That was not asked for in this one.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that: (a) You use the intervals of varied lengths; (b) Points such as $T$ are also covered (though you don't exactly explain how - would be nice to show).

Comment: OK I see that the corners are covered. But what about the points like $T$ that @StinkingBishop notes? You seem still to have a grid of squares uncovered.

Comment: Stinking Bishop would now pass a horizontal line through T which would additionally split two of those four triangles into two, and now we can fill those six triangles (two big and two small) - I guess... @Exodd Is that the idea?

Comment: @EthanBolker if you look better, RQ is a single segment, that passesà through T

Comment: @StinkingBishop no need to do that. RQ is a segment that covers T

Comment: Ah, I see. But then you can simplify your solution further. If the diagonal lines all together make a grid and all points on the grid are covered, then forget all about "straight up" squares and triangles, and just fill in those bigger, rotated (by $45^\circ$) squares - would that work? That way you would only use lines of length $1$ and $2$ (or, rather $\sqrt{2}$ and $2\sqrt{2}$ on your picture)..

Comment: Re: "add diagonal segments of length 2–√2": But the question specifies that all segments should have the same length.

Comment: @ruakh the OP never said SAME length, but just finite lengths

Comment: @Exodd: The OP specified "with length $||P-Q||=b-a$". (S)he didn't use the specific word "same", but achieved exactly that effect by specifying a single value for the length of all segments.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it can be done.  Here is a recursive construction that uses only axis-aligned segments.  Start by covering the open unit square $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ with horizontal segments.  Then, given an initial open square, make 8 more copies and arrange them around the initial square, producing a larger open square with an uncovered hash symbol or octothorpe (#).  Then cover the octothorpe with two long horizontal segments and six short vertical segments.  You’ve now tripled the size of the initial open square.  Repeating this indefinitely covers all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

It is an interesting question whether there is a covering using segments that are all the same length.  The best I see right now is a covering using segments of length $1$ and countably many segments of length $2$.

Comment: Note that the question specifies that all segments have to be the same length.

Answer (score 3):

In fact it is impossible with open intervals, although you can do it with closed intervals:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43611/decomposing-the-plane-into-intervals

Comment: Jeff Strom's answer to that question cites a paper by Conway and Croft that has a beautiful figure that is a sufficient proof for closed intervals.  Unfortunately, I lost my copy and cannot find it on the web (it was behind a paywall, but now I don't find it at all).

Comment: Could you tell me what's wrong with my solution?

Comment: In the linked question the intervals all had to be the same length, which is not asked here.

Comment: @RossMillikan $||P-Q||=b-a$ is the requirement for all the intervals to be the same length.

Comment: @Exodd, I am slowly coming to terms with it.  Also, as Ross mentioned in a comment, there is an important difference whether or not you require all intervals to have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the intervals can be of different lengths, I think it can be done. I sketched something on a paper and it seems to me like this is a solution that only uses 2 different lengths for the intervals, namely $1$ and $\frac 12$:

First, create a fabric-looking structure from horizontal intervals of the form $(m, m+1) \times \{k\}$ and $\left(m+\frac 12, m+\frac 32\right) \times \left\{k+\frac 12\right\}$ and vertical ones of the form $\{k\} \times \left(m+\frac 12, m+\frac 32\right)$ and $\left\{k+\frac 12\right\}\times(m,m+1)$, $\forall k,m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then just complete it with parallel segments of length $\frac 12$, for example, with all-vertical segments: $\{k+r\}\times\left(m,m+\frac 12\right), \{k+r\}\times\left(m+\frac 12, m+1\right)$, $\forall k,m \in\mathbb{Z}, r\in(0,1)\setminus\left\{\frac 12\right\}$.

I would have added an illustration, but all I have is a pen-on-paper sketch and I'm using a phone. I can add a photo of that if requested.